# How to use watchdog in AVR microcontroller

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, avr, watchdog

Hi I'm working on watchdog but I'm bit confused It show me some errors. I'm using AVR(AVR128DB48).

Errors:

```
WDTO_4S' undeclared (first use in this function)
recipe for target 'main.o' failed
```

code:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/wdt.h>

int main(void)
{
    wdt_enable(WDTO_4S);

    while(1)
    {
        wdt_reset();
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: looks like it isn't supported: https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__watchdog.html#ga752b0b1b5ba9009bc09976494313e30d

Comment: when you grepped for that define what did you find?  And when you looked through the include directories did you find other registers that matched the AVR documentation?  And from that information were you able to create your own define?  And what were the results of that experiment?

Comment: @AhmedMasud That's actually not a valid reason to close a question. If you think it lacks research, then there's down votes for that. Also _DO NOT_ edit out all programming language tags from a question, it screws up code formatting. Questions containing C code _should_ be tagged with C, always. Or in case there is reason to believe it is compiled with a C++ compiler, tag with C++ only. See C and C++ tag wikis for tag usage guidance.

Comment: Try reading the datasheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never used this part, but I can do a quick Google search. From the inline documentation the header itself:

> #define WDTO_4S   8
>
> Note: This is only available on the ATtiny2313, ATtiny24, ATtiny44, ATtiny84, ATtiny25, ATtiny45, ATtiny85, ATtiny261, ATtiny461, ATtiny861, ATmega48, ATmega88, ATmega168, ATmega48P, ATmega88P, ATmega168P, ATmega328P, ATmega164P, ATmega324P, ATmega644P, ATmega644, ATmega640, ATmega1280, ATmega1281, ATmega2560, ATmega2561, ATmega8HVA, ATmega16HVA, ATmega32HVB, ATmega406, ATmega1284P, AT90PWM1, AT90PWM2, AT90PWM2B, AT90PWM3, AT90PWM3B, AT90PWM216, AT90PWM316, AT90PWM81, AT90USB82, AT90USB162, AT90USB646, AT90USB647, AT90USB1286, AT90USB1287, ATtiny48, ATtiny88.

[See Here](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__watchdog.html)